# изменить favicon в поддомене

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Есть сайт something.com у которого свой favicon. Также есть под-домен some.something.com, они написаны на angular и имеют общий `index.html`, а страницы уже подгружаются `<ng-view>`. Можно ли изменить favicon для под-домена, в голову приходит только `removeChild` - удалить действующий favicon  с `<head>` и append - вставить новый.. Но может есть вариант попроще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все было бы проще, если было возможно просто поменять у `<link rel="icon"/>` `src`, все были бы счастливы. А так придется удалять элемент, и создавать новый, с новым путем до картинки.

В твоем случае нужно сделать директиву, которая будет проверять текущий домен и наличие под-домена, и вставлять нужную, в принципе это код в одно условие.

Код будет примерно таким:

```
Если есть под-домен
   ссылка №1
иначе
   ссылка №2
```

При этом `ng-app` должна будет висеть в корне (html).

А если нужна динамика, то с `link` можно только удалять элемент и создавать новый в `head`. Просто поменять `src` не сработает.